# Extract a specific string from a variable

Tags: python

I want to extract the last part of multiple strings from a variable using `splitext()`

Currently i can do the same for image names in a folder. I have a path from which i want to extract the last parts having the folder name

```
folders = glob(input_frames_folder)

img_list = []

for folder in folders:
    print(folder)
    for f in glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
        img_list.append(f)


for i in range(len(img_list)):
    #print(img_list[i])
    v1=os.path.basename(img_list[i])
    #print(v1)
    img_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
```

Suppose this is the value of the FOLDER variable. `C:\Python36\videos\videos_new\video_tiger_leopard`. I want to extract only video_tiger_leopard from this FOLDER variable. There will be multiple values in the variable as per the current folder being read

Comment: See `os.path.basename()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this using split() ;

```
path = r"C:\Python36\videos\videos_new\video_tiger_leopard" ;
li = path.split("\\") ;

print(li[len(li) - 1]) ; #return video_tiger_leopard
```

be aware that your input contains backslashes, to ignore them either use two backslashes

`path = "C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new\\video_tiger_leopard"`

or use raw_input for taking the path input.